# Order of mix functions executed - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, replace, trim

I have the below piece of code and i was wondering which of the included fucntions are executed first.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

`Replace(Replace(Replace(Application.Clean(Application.Trim("Test")), "(", ""), ")", ""), "'", "")`

Comment: The last function always execute first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered by easily located documentation: [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence).

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Trim("Test")
```

Then go back to `Clean`, `Replace`, `Replace`...

Answer (score 0):

In VBA (and most programming languages), expressions (combinations of functions, constants, and operators, which return a value) are **executed from the innermost, rightmost part**.

So, in your code, `Application.Trim("Test")` is executed first, then `Clean`, then three `Replace`s from the inside to the outside.

You might find it easier to understand the code if you rewrite it to use variables for the intermediate results as follows.

```
Dim a, b, c, d, result

a = Application.Trim("Test")
b = Application.Clean(a)
c = Replace(b, "(", "")
d = Replace(c, ")", "")
result = Replace(d, "'", "")
```